# OpenShot: How to export a 1920x800 video in its original resolution?

Tags: video-editing

I'm editing a video using OpenShot that has a resolution of 1920x800, but when I want to export the video (without having cropped it or anything), there is no option to save it in the same resolution. The closest is 1920x1080, but that's a different aspect ratio and the saved video has a black frame around it. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find the profile meets your needs, you can define one to meet your needs, in your case, a profile with width=1920, height=800.

Other than the width and height, you also need frame rate and two aspect ratio numbers.

Add the video to OpenShot and left-click to choose **File Properties**, from there, you will see two number in the **Aspect Ratio:** row under Video Details pane, the one on the right is **display_aspect_den**=x
the one on the right is **display_aspect_num**=y.
Take note what the **x** and **y** are in your case.

Once you have these, now you can start defining a profile that works for you. Here's the how-to:

1. Locate the profile folder from your OpenShot home directory
   In case of Windows 10, 64-bit, the path is such **C:\Program Files\OpenShot Video Editor\profiles**
2. Open a text editor, such as Notepad for Window users and add following contents:

   ```
    description=Custom Vertical 1080p 30fps
    frame_rate_num=30
    frame_rate_den=1
    width=1920
    height=1080
    progressive=1
    sample_aspect_num=1
    sample_aspect_den=1
    display_aspect_num=y
    display_aspect_den=x
    colorspace=709
   ```

Note: Replace the **x, y** with the numbers you found out. You can also change the description and/or frame rate number to suite your needs.

3. Save it to something like "**my_customized_profile.txt**"and drag this file to the profile folder.
4. Open OpenShot(mine is version 2.5.1) now and you shall see the customized profile you just defined. (File > Choose Profile), choose it before adding the video.
5. If this helps you, enjoy!